# jquery - $.getJson - how to pass an argument to a method?

Tags: jquery

I have this function which executes an MVC method. That method requires a `profileCategoryId` argument.

---

I get the error:

> {0}The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'profileCategoryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult] ListForDropDown(Int32)' in 'GbngWebClient.Controllers.UserProfileController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

---

In the script I see that `profileCategoryId` is grayed out and it states that it is declared but its value is never used.

How do I pass that argument to the method?
Am I doing it correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var profileCategoryId = 5;

    $.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/ListForDropDown", function (profileCategoryId) {
        var items1 = '';

        items1 += "<option value='" + "" + "'>" + "---- Select ----" + "</option>";

        $("#StateID").empty();

        $.each(data, function (i, values) {
            items1 += "<option value='" + values.SelectionId + "'>" + values.Description + "</option>";
        });

        $('#StateID').html(items1);
    });
});
```

---

Here's the method being called:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ListForDropDown(int profileCategoryId)
{
    Doing stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), the second parameter of [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function is for data,

```
$.getJSON(url, { profileCategoryId: profileCategoryId }, function(data) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's expecting that value on the query string.  So where you currently build your URL:

```
'@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/ListForDropDown"
```

You'd add the value:

```
'@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/ListForDropDown?profileCategoryId=" + profileCategoryId
```

Note also that you *wouldn't* put it in the callback function arguments:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/ListForDropDown?profileCategoryId=" + profileCategoryId, function () {
  //...
});
```

The only argument(s) to that function would be what the server is returning.  Looking at your callback function, I suspect that's what you expect `data` to be:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/ListForDropDown?profileCategoryId=" + profileCategoryId, function (data) {
  //...
});
```

Comment: David, I'm using routing attributes, so when I use: "UserProfile/ListForDropDown=" + profileCategoryId, function (data), I get that it cannot find: /UserProfile/ListForDropDown=5. When I use: "UserProfile/ListForDropDown/" + profileCategoryId, function (data), I get the same error above. The only 1 that worked is: "UserProfile/ListForDropDown", { profileCategoryId: 5 }, function (data)

Comment: @user3020047: That should work too, yes.  But it's worth noting that the attempts you made weren't what I'd suggested.  Note the difference between `"UserProfile/ListForDropDown=" + profileCategoryId` and `"UserProfile/ListForDropDown?profileCategoryId=" + profileCategoryId`  As you continue in web development, it's worth taking note of how query string parameters are formed.  They will come up again.

Comment: David..I must have been tired as I did not do as you instructed. But this time i did. and I get: Deferred exception: profileCategoryId is not defined ReferenceError: profileCategoryId is not defined. I tried both of these and get that message. "UserProfile/ListForDropDown?profileCategoryId=" + profileCategoryId, function (data) {...
"UserProfile/ListForDropDown/profileCategoryId/" + profileCategoryId, function (data) {...

Comment: @user3020047: The variable isn't defined?  In the code you're showing it's defined on the line immediately before this.  Has that changed?  You'd indicated in your first comment that the other answer's structure worked, but you'd also indicated you were using the hard-coded value of `5`.  Does that structure work with the variable?  (I notice you haven't accepted the other answer, so I wonder if you're still experiencing the issue.)  If so then it sounds like there would be a typo somewhere, because the variable is either defined or it isn't.

Comment: No, it had not changed for those 2 examples: var profileCategoryId = 5;  I changed my hard coded 5 and replaced it with the profileCategoryId. It works with the variable or the hardcode. So all is good.